# Можно пересоздать переменную но с другим типом C#

Tags: c#

Можно пересоздать переменную но с другим типом C#.
У меня есть такой код например

```
string login = "TEst";
//Чё то сделал
//И мне нужна уже другой тип переменной но стаким же имнеем
Login login = new Login(password);
```

Это пример кода который я хочу сделать.

А лучше вообще удалить переменную если можно.

Comment: А использовать касты запрещено?)

Comment: можно обернуть в скобочки { } кусок кода с логином строкой, тем самым сделав этот код локальным. А после скобок уже можно использовать это же название переменной в других скобках. Но это такое себе решение, лучше всего код вынести в разные функции, либо назвать как-то по другому / кастовать в нужный тип.

Comment: @SultanovShamil ты можешь пожалуйста, написать пример кода?

Comment: У вас не должно быть в переменной, которые создаете вы сами несколько типов. Такое допустимо например при получение с сервера данных, когда сервер отдает ответом в одной переменный разный тип данных. Но ваш код выше - это бред... Делайте тогда `object` и в нужных местах сверяйте тип, но это костыль. Самое лучшее в вашем случае - это использовать другое имя, например `userLogin`, а еще лучше, создать класс `User` и у него реализовать свойства, тогда будет уже `User.Login`, что согласитесь в разы понятней. Ну или разбивайте код на куски, на разные методы и в них держите локальную переменную.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ :} Очень не приятно если Login это массив Char'ов

Comment: А я сказал где то про массив и про char?

Comment: Если вы что-то терпите, то ваше проектирование приложения неверно. Уточните тогда в вопросе что конкретно вы хотите.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ можно использовать `{string login = "aa"}; {int login = 2}`

Comment: Это грубо говоря разделение на методы, да.

Comment: А что, у нас переменные в ограниченном количестве, что их имена надо всеми силами экономить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант №1 - переменная с типом **object**:

```
object login = "TEst";
//Чё то сделал
//И мне нужна уже другой тип переменной но с таким же именем
login = new Login(password);
```

Вариант №2 - ограничение области видимости:

```
{
    string login = "TEst";
    //Чё то сделал
}

//И мне нужна уже другой тип переменной но с таким же именем
{
  Login login = new Login(password);
  //далее что-то делаем с login
}
```